# PHP email does nothing when I press send on GoDaddy

Tags: php

I'm hosting my website off of godaddy running windows and php 5.4  and my contact form is not sending. Here is the PHPcode which is kept in htdocs/php. I have tried several attempts to make changes to get it to work.

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mailer module
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These module are used when sending email from contact form
|
*/



/*SECTION I - CONFIGURATION*/

//$receiver_mail = 'youremail@example.com';
$receiver_mail = 'youremail@example.com';
$mail_title = '[Contact Form Submission]';



/*SECTION II - CODE*/
print_r($_POST)

if( !empty($_POST['input-name']) && !empty($_POST['input-mail']) && !empty($_POST['input-message']) )
{
$subject = $mail_title.' message from '.$_POST['input-name'];
$header = 'From: '.$_POST['input-mail'].'\r\nReply-To: '.$_POST['input-mail'];
   if ( mail($receiver_mail, $subject, htmlentities($_POST['input-message']), 'From: contactform@thebigbeatsinc.com') )
      $result = "Your message was successfully sent.";
   else
      $result = "Operation could not be completed.";
}
else
{
     $result = "Error processing your request.";
}
//echo $result;
echo "Your message was successfully sent.";
?>
```

And the HTML:

```
 <form class="contactForm" action="php/contact.php" method="post" target="_blank">
        <div class="contactFormTitle font1">
            don't be shy, come along & say hi
        </div>
        <fieldset class="contactFormDetails">
            <input type="text" name="input-name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="text" name="input-mail" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="contactFormMessage">
            <textarea rows="" cols="" name="input-message" placeholder="Type your message here"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="contactFormButtons">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Start troubleshooting. First before the if statement. print_r($_POST) to make sure the data is being sent to the script.

Comment: side note -if its not to late, leave godaddy - worst host ever.

Comment: i have applied print_r($_post) above the if statement but nothing happens when I press send. I can only assume that mean nothing is being sent to the script?

Comment: Add attribute target="_blank" to the form and see if it opens a new page. if $_POST is empty print_r($_POST) should at least print "Array()"

Comment: $_post !=$_POST , but of course you have to add `method="post"` first

Comment: @Dragon good catch on the $_post thing.
Dark9911: make sure you're typing print_r($_POST) and not print_r($_post). And remember the attention to detail.

Comment: Evade and Dragon thank you! I have posted print_r($_POST) into the PHP, added method="post" and target="blank". When I upload to server and try to send nothing happens still. I have updated my original post to show the changes

Comment: These things are only for testing. We want to see the results of this. And it's target="_blank" not target="blank". The reason for this, is to see if the form is executing at all. So add target="_blank" to see if it opens a new page. And at the least Array() should be printed on it.

Comment: I understand. I have target="_blank"  sorry for the typo in my comment. When I go to my webpage and click submit nothing happens.

Comment: If clicking submit after adding target="_blank" doesn't open a new page, then you need to check through your html to make sure all of your tags have closing '>' and closing tags, ie '</div>' and especially that all of your attributes have closing quotations.

Comment: Okay I will look and see if I can find anything. Thank you Evade

Comment: i see syntax errors resulting in  the blank page as you don't have error checking\display on

Comment: Yeah another biggie, with as many things as you miss, you'll have to start putting ini_set('display_errors', '1') at the top of your pages until you finish building them, so you'll see what random things you mess up in the syntax. Then take that line of code out when you are finished writing the script.

Comment: Dragon I am unsure what that means - I am fairly new to PHP and do not know what blank page you are talking about? I can only assume the blank page that you speak of should pop up when you click submit due to the target=_"blank" attribute.

Evade- I am assuming that is a PHP code that I place at the top of my contact.php? 
I am still new but willing to do the work in order to learn what needs to be done. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Update - I have run all my HTML through an HTML 5 checker and have corrected all errors on the whole website. There was not many thank god! lol I still am new to php so I am having a difficult time with this code smh

Answer (score 1):

You need to add method attribute:

```
<form class="contactForm" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
```

You also should work on a process of troubleshooting and more attention to detail, or you will be spending a lot of time on forums, trying to figure out why your code isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried method="post" several times and it still is not working. I just put it back and tried the website. Still nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: You have to have method post on the form, for it to submit post variables to the back-end. On your php file print_r($_POST) at the top of the page to ensure that it's receiving your variables in the first place. In troubleshooting you need to test each step of the process. Getting the post variables is the first step.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it needed to be there cause on my other sites I have it and they work. This particular new webpage I made is giving me the run around.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

With GoDaddy the from parameter need to be an email under you're domain name

```
    if ( mail($receiver_mail, $subject, htmlentities($_POST['input-message']), 'From: contactform@thebigbeatsinc.com') )
        $result = "Your message was successfully sent.";
    else
        $result = "Operation could not be completed.";
```

And you should also add the method post to you're form balise as specified by Evade Captcha

Comment: that's invalid syntax for a header paramater

Comment: @Dagon That's true just fixed it thanks :)

Comment: Also $_POST[] user input variables shouldn't be directly inserted into things like this. Edit: Better :)